# How to save tranformed data into Usestate constant after Transforming(Slicing) another another useState in React Js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, scripting

> Hi Experts, I am new to react and stuck with below issue.
> I have a Getfulldata function in which, I am using setFulltoursdata(copy) method to get pure data.

```
     const [Fulltoursdata, setFulltoursdata] = useState([]);
  const [Trimmedtoursdata, setTrimmedtoursdata] = useState([]);    

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetchData();
    Getfulldata();
  }, []);

  const Getfulldata = async () => {
    await fetch("https://course-api.com/react-tours-project")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((reponsefulldata) => {
        let copy = [...reponsefulldata];
        console.log(copy);

        setFulltoursdata(copy);
        settoursdata([...reponsefulldata]);
        setIsLoaded(true);
        return reponsefulldata;
      })
      .then((dataobject) => {
        const filteredTourinfo = dataobject.map((tour) => {
          tour.info = tour.info.slice(0, 120) + "....";
          return tour;
        });
        let Trimmedcopy = [...filteredTourinfo];
        setTrimmedtoursdata([...filteredTourinfo]);
      });
  };
```

> fetching api data.

```
      .then((reponsefulldata) => {
        let copy = [...reponsefulldata]; 
        console.log(copy);
        setFulltoursdata(copy);
```

> Trying to make copy of reponsefulldata
> Setting Fulltoursdata using setFulltoursdata()

```
        return reponsefulldata;
      })
```

> After which, using **then** method I am trying to use slice method to update one column i.e. info in each array object. This needs to be Set into another state object i.e. Trimmedtoursdata.

```
.then((dataobject) => {
        const filteredTourinfo = dataobject.map((tour) => {
          tour.info = tour.info.slice(0, 120) + "....";
          return tour;
        });

        let Trimmedcopy = [...filteredTourinfo];
        setTrimmedtoursdata([...filteredTourinfo]);
```

> Setting filteredTourinfousing setTrimmedtoursdata(). so setting Trimmedtoursdata should not effect Fulltoursdata.

> Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is basically concept of shallow copy and deep copy. I created a deep copy using below.

let Trimmedcopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filteredTourinfo));